# Jogo da Velha em C com MiniMax. Problema ao imprimir as jogadas

Tags: c, c++, estrutura-de-dados, jogos

Eu e mais dois amigos estamos fazendo um jogo da velha em C utilizando MiniMax e árvore como projeto de Estrutura de Dados e estamos com problema na hora de receber a jogada, e também na hora de mostrá-la para o usuário. Acreditamos que é provável que o erro esteja nessa linha do código: `jogada(&(*arv)->posicao[play], jogaPrimeiro, (t+1)%2);`, porém ainda sim não conseguimos consertar. Qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda.

Segue o código completo e com alguns comentários:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Raiz = Max.
//Bolinha = 2 (turno ímpar)
//Xis = 1 (turno par)

int vetorDisponibilidadeJogada[9];
int vetorJogadas[9];

typedef struct node
{
    int tabuleiro[9];
    int minimax;
    node *posicao[9];
    int jogada;
} node;

void inicializar(node **arv);
void inicializaVetorPossibilidades();
void funcaoRecursivaPossibilidades(node **arv, int alturaDaArvore, int dificuldade);
int insere(node **arv, int dificuldade, int *vetor, int turno);
int acabou(node **arv);
void jogada(node **arv, int quemJoga, int t); //quemJoga deve ser 0 ou 1 (0 = Vc, 1 = IA)
void imprime(int *vetor);

//void imprimeLinha(node **arv){
//  int i;
//  for(i=0; i<9; i++){
//      imprime((*arv)->posicao[i]->tabuleiro);
//  }
//}

main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int dificuldade, jogaPrimeiro, i;
    node *raiz, *nutella;
    inicializaVetorPossibilidades();
    inicializar(&raiz);

    do
    {
        printf("\nEscolha a dificuldade [1-9]: ");
        scanf("%i", &dificuldade);
        fflush(stdin);
    }while (dificuldade < 1 and dificuldade > 9);

    funcaoRecursivaPossibilidades(&raiz, 0, dificuldade);

    //imprimeLinha(&raiz);

    do
    {
        printf("\nEscolha quem joga primeiro [0 -> Usuário - 1 -> IA]: ");
        scanf("%i", &jogaPrimeiro);
        fflush(stdin);
    }while (jogaPrimeiro < 0 and jogaPrimeiro > 1);

    jogada(&raiz, jogaPrimeiro, 0);
}

void inicializar(node **arv)
{
    *arv = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        (*arv)->posicao[i] = NULL;
        (*arv)->tabuleiro[i] = 0;
    }
}

void inicializaVetorPossibilidades ()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        vetorDisponibilidadeJogada[i] = 1;

}

void funcaoRecursivaPossibilidades(node **arv, int alturaDaArvore, int dificuldade)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (alturaDaArvore == dificuldade)
    {
        insere(&(*arv), dificuldade, vetorJogadas, 0);
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){    
            if (vetorDisponibilidadeJogada[i] == 1)
            {
                vetorDisponibilidadeJogada[i] = 0;
                vetorJogadas[alturaDaArvore] = i;

                funcaoRecursivaPossibilidades(arv, alturaDaArvore + 1, dificuldade);

                vetorDisponibilidadeJogada[i] = 1;
            }
        }   
    }
}

int insere(node **arv, int dificuldade, int *vetor, int turno)
{
    int i, comp;

    if(turno == dificuldade) return 0;//conferir isto

    if(!((*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]))//se o prox nó ainda não foi alocado, ele é alocado, inicializado, recebe o estado atual do tabuleiro e a nova jogada
    {

        ((*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]) = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
        inicializar(&(*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]);//zera todo o tabuleiro e faz todos ponteiros apontarem para NULL

        //minimax deve receber a pior possibilidade aqui
        (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->minimax = ((turno+1)%2)+1;//inicializa o valor de minimax de acordo com a pior possibilidade
        // 1<0; 2>0>1

        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->tabuleiro[i] = (*arv)->tabuleiro[i];//copia o nó atual para o que está sendo alocado

        (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->tabuleiro[turno] = (turno%2 + 1);//faz a nova jogada no tabuleiro que foi alocado
    }

    if(!acabou(&(*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]))//se o jogo ainda não acabou, continua alocando as jogadas
    {
        comp = insere(&(*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]], dificuldade, vetor, turno+1);//comp recebe o minimax propagado pela função ate aqui
        //se o turno for 1, minimax recebe o menor se for 2 recebe o maior

        if(comp == ((turno)%2)+1)//o retorno é o desejado?
        {
            (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->minimax = comp;

        }else 
            if(!comp and (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->minimax != ((turno)%2)+1)//o retorno é 0 E eu ainda não tenho o desejado?
            {
                (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->minimax = comp;
            }
    }else
        {
            (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->minimax = acabou(&(*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]);//minimax sabe quem ganhou quando o jogo acaba
        }

    return (*arv)->posicao[vetor[turno]]->minimax;//propaga o minimax para a chamada recursiva
}

int acabou(node **arv)
{
    int i, j, v[3];

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            v[j] = (*arv)->tabuleiro[(i * 3) + j];

        if(v[0] == v[1] and v[0] == v[2] and v[0]) 
            return v[0];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            v[j] = (*arv)->tabuleiro[(j * 3) + i];

        if(v[0] == v[1] and v[0] == v[2] and v[0]) 
            return v[0];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        v[i] = (*arv)->tabuleiro[(i * 3) + i];

    if(v[0] == v[1] and v[0] == v[2] and v[0]) 
        return v[0];

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        v[i] = (*arv)->tabuleiro[(i * 3) + 2 - i];

    if(v[0] == v[1] and v[0] == v[2] and v[0]) 
        return v[0];

    return 0;
}

void jogada (node **arv, int jogaPrimeiro, int t)
{
    int play, i, eleito, minimaxAtual, desejado;
    node *ponteiro;
    imprime((*arv)->tabuleiro);

    if(acabou(&(*arv))) 
        return;

    if(jogaPrimeiro)
    {
        minimaxAtual = 2;
        desejado = 1;
    }else
        {
            minimaxAtual = 1;
            desejado = 2;
        }

    if (!((t+jogaPrimeiro)%2))
    {
        printf("\nEscolha sua jogada [0-8]: ");
        scanf("%d", &play);
        fflush(stdin);
        jogada(&(*arv)->posicao[play], jogaPrimeiro, (t+1)%2);
    }else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if(!(*arv)->tabuleiro[i])
            {
                if((*arv)->posicao[i]->minimax==minimaxAtual)
                {
                    eleito = i;
                }else
                    {
                        if((*arv)->posicao[i]->minimax==desejado)
                        {
                            minimaxAtual = desejado;
                            eleito = i;
                        }else 
                            if((*arv)->posicao[i]->minimax==0&&minimaxAtual!=desejado)
                            {
                                minimaxAtual = 0;
                                eleito = i;
                            }
                    }
            }
        }
        jogada(&(*arv)->posicao[eleito], jogaPrimeiro, (t+1)%2);
    }


}

void imprime(int *vetor)
{
    int i, j;
    char jogada[9];

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(vetor[i] == 1) jogada[i] = 'X';
        if(vetor[i] == 2) jogada[i] = 'O';
        if(vetor[i] == 0) jogada[i] = ' ';
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf(" %c | %c | %c\t\t\t %i | %i | %i\n", jogada[(i * 3) + 0], jogada[(i * 3) + 1], jogada[(i * 3) + 2], (i * 3) + 0, (i * 3) + 1, (i * 3) + 2);
        if(i < 2)
        printf("---+---+---\t\t\t---+---+---\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow, Jean! Você pode incluir o erro que você recebe ao executar o programa (completo se possível) - Ah, e faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer um pouco mais sobre o site... :)

Comment: Por favor especifique (dê mais detalhes) sobre o problema que você está encontrando para que o leitor entenda facilmente como seu código deveria funcionar e o ajude de maneira objetiva.